# Cast $casts to float but only one decimal place

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.5

In my model I added `$casts` field because I need Laravel to give me a float. My database is storing it as a string.

So I did this in my model `Score.php`:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Score extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'value', 'comment'
    ];

    protected $casts = [
        'user_id' => 'int',
        'value' => 'float'
    ];
```

This is great, it casts it. However it is going wayyyy too many decimal places. I need it to go only 1 decimal place, to the tenths.

My json endpoint data looks like this:

```
{
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Zed",
    "avatar_path": null,
    "score": {
        "id": 2,
        "value": 9.9000000000000003552713678800500929355621337890625,
        "comment": null,
        "user_id": 2,
        "created_at": "2018-05-03 07:03:37",
        "updated_at": "2018-05-03 07:03:41"
    }
},
```

I want that `9.9......` to just be `9.9` is this possible?

In my schema, I did i do it right to create it as `$table->decimal('value', 3, 1)`:

```
    Schema::create('scores', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->decimal('value', 3, 1)->nullable(); //////// is this correct?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about creating a mutator/accessor?

In your model add

```
public function getValueAttribute($value) {
    return round($value, 1);
}
```

for extra info visit the related [Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-mutators)

If you are 100% sure you only need one decimal place, than the database approach is good too, but this way you can store the raw value for future use, and still respond with the currently desired format

Comment: Thanks this is intersting I'll try it out!

Comment: Is there a perf difference between using cast and using accessor? Does casts internally just do accessor themselves? I am already using the database approach but its still giving me so many decimal places :( - i was hoping to avoid accessor.